# Trying to track where each download came from in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, analytics, affiliate

Does anyone know if it’s possible to track where each download came from? ie I invite you to download the app, if you download it then your account would be tagged to my invitation. Similar to an affiliate program I guess.
If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is also looking for this the best solution hands down is the [Branch](https://branch.io) SDK.